# Incluir un archivo en ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Buenas tardes, trato de hacer un include en mi archivo aspx. pero al hacerlo me lo pone en forma de comentario.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" Explicit="True" Debug="true"%>
<!-- #INCLUDE FILE="lib-login.aspx" -->
<!-- #INCLUDE FILE="lib-sportcity.aspx" -->
```

El problema es el que describo a continuación, tengo el siguiente método en "lib-sportcity.aspx":

```
  Public Function SCC_ObtenConfiguracionClub(
                                   ByVal sDbServidores As String,
                                   ByVal sIP As String,
                                   ByRef sDBConexion As String,
                                   ByRef sDBSolomon As String,
                                   ByRef sClubId As String,
                                   ByRef sClubName As String
) As Boolean
```

Y trato de acceder a el en "login.aspx":

```
If SCC_ObtenConfiguracionClub(
                  Application("ConexionServidores"),
                  Request.ServerVariables("LOCAL_ADDR"),
                  sConexion,
                  sDBSolomon,
                  sClubId,
                  sClubName)
```

Pero me marca un error al tratar de acceder a el, lo mismo me pasa con otra página.

Podrían ayudarme ? Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿El código lo tienes en el .aspx, y no en el .aspx.vb? No entiendo qué debería hacer al incluir un aspx, ¿dónde va a colocar ese contenido?

Comment: Solo tengo código .aspx, ningún .aspx.vb

Comment: Entiendo que ese include mete el contenido del aspx exactamente en ese lugar, lo cual significa que estás fuera del tag html y body. Me parece medio caótico.
Si te interesa hacerlo de una manera más prolija, probablemente te sirva esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894720/asp-net-equivalent-of-server-side-includes O también: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/144/classic-asp-include-files-in-asp-net

Comment: Aunque incluya los archivos con el Response.WriteFile me sigue marcando error en esas líneas, no importa si los incluyo dentro del HTML o afuera del script, de todos modos marca error.

Comment: Inclusive ya trate de la siguiente manera y nada :                                              <%@ Reference Page="~/lib-login.aspx" %>
<%@ Reference Page="~/lib-sql.aspx" %>
<%@ Reference Page="~/lib-sportcity.aspx" %>

Comment: ¿Y no puedes hacer como lo indican las guías que te mencioné? ¿Cuál es el contenido de cada archivo y por qué los quieres incluir? ¿No deberían ser user controls? Aquí puedes ver cómo se usa `Reference`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840985/asp-net-register-vs-reference O también aquí: https://weblogs.asp.net/johnkatsiotis/the-reference-directive

Comment: Los quiero incluir para poder utilizar los métodos declarados en los archivos "lib-...".

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63297/discussion-between-andrew-and-guillermo-ricardo-spindola-bri).

Answer (score 0):

Intenta eso:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="NAMESPACE" %>
```

donde NAMESPACE será en namespace donde tengas alojado el método.

Comment: Pues no tengo ningún namespace, solo tengo los archivos.aspx

Comment: Todo aspx tiene su .vb o .cs, según utilices Visual Basic .Net o C#. El problema es que usando vb este no se ve por defecto. Tienes dos opciones para acceder a el:  A) pulsando F7 en el .aspx o bien, en el Explorador de soluciones, pulsando sobre el icono de "Mostrar todos los archivos". De esta forma podrás ver todos los .vb. Si colocas tus métodos en los vb podrás acceder a ellos a través de otras páginas.